# Set of all subsequential limits of an unbounded sequence

Tags: real-analysis, sequences-and-series, limits

How can I define the set of all subsequential limits of the following sequence: $x_n = ln(n) + cos(n)$?
I have proved the following property: since $x_n$ is unbounded it has a divergent subsequence, whose limit is infinity, but what can I say about the set of all subsequential (as well as superior and inferior) limits?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

$\mathbf{Hint}$: if $\lim_{n\to\infty} x_n=\pm\infty$ or $\lim_{n\to\infty} x_n=L\in\Bbb R$, then $$\limsup_{n\to\infty} x_n=\lim_{n\to\infty} x_n=\liminf_{n\to\infty} x_n$$